# Adding a footer to QPrintWidget, QPrintPreviwWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

My Invoice

[image]

I have a almost finishd project in Python which uses QPrintPreviwDialog to show and print data according to the picture above. I have used QTextDocumento to handle the HTML.

Is there a way to write something in page number space. I would like to write the info in yellow to the page number space to serve as footer. Or is there other solution to show footer instead of using pyjasper, one that are not part of python?

Comment: In SO you must ask a question per post, that's beacuse Ask Question says, it does not say Ask Questions. Read [ask] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44540195/6622587) from C++ to python and modifying the position of the text I show how to add a footer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport

textMargins = 12
borderMargins = 10

def mmToPixels(printer, mm):
    return mm * 0.039370147 * printer.resolution()

def paintPage(pageNumber, pageCount, painter, doc, textRect, footerHeight):
    painter.save()
    textPageRect = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(0, pageNumber*doc.pageSize().height()), doc.pageSize())
    painter.setClipRect(textRect)
    painter.translate(0, -textPageRect.top())
    painter.translate(textRect.left(), textRect.top())
    doc.drawContents(painter)
    painter.restore()
    footerRect = QtCore.QRectF(textRect)
    footerRect.setTop(textRect.bottom())
    footerRect.setHeight(footerHeight)

    # draw footer
    painter.save()
    pen = painter.pen()
    pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)
    painter.setPen(pen)
    painter.drawText(footerRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, "Page {} of {}".format(pageNumber+1, pageCount))
    painter.restore()


def printDocument(printer, doc):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
    doc.documentLayout().setPaintDevice(printer)
    doc.setPageSize(QtCore.QSizeF(printer.pageRect().size()))
    pageSize = printer.pageRect().size()
    tm = mmToPixels(printer, textMargins)
    footerHeight = painter.fontMetrics().height()
    textRect = QtCore.QRectF(tm, tm, pageSize.width() - 2 * tm, pageSize.height() - 2 * tm - footerHeight)
    doc.setPageSize(textRect.size())
    pageCount = doc.pageCount()

    for pageIndex in range(pageCount):
        if pageIndex != 0:
            printer.newPage()
        paintPage(pageIndex, pageCount, painter, doc, textRect, footerHeight)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
    cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
    blockFormat = QtGui.QTextBlockFormat()

    for i in range(10):
        cursor.insertBlock(blockFormat)
        cursor.insertHtml("<h1>This is the {} page</h1>".format(i+1))
        blockFormat.setPageBreakPolicy(QtGui.QTextFormat.PageBreak_AlwaysBefore)

    printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.HighResolution)
    printer.setPageSize(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.A4)
    printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)

    dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog(printer)
    dialog.paintRequested.connect(lambda print, doc=document: printDocument(printer, doc))


    dialog.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked fine and helped me solve a long time problem.