# Change typing of page number in QPrinter

Tags: python, pyqt5, numbers, qprinter, qtextdocument

How can I change the typing of the page number, for example:
1 of 4 if it contains 4 pages

```
    self.printer = QPrinter()
    self.printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
    self.printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Portrait)
    self.printer.setFullPage(True)
    #self.printer.setPageMargins(20, 20, 20, 20, QPrinter.Millimeter)
    dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(self.printer)
    if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        self.preparationData(gnum)
```

I've used it via QTextDocument()
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no direct way to customize page numbering (or adding any header/footer) in printing. The only solution is to override the `print` function that draws on the QPrinter the content of each page and manually create the page numbers on the paint device. It can be done, but that's *not* easy.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073747/adding-a-footer-to-qprintwidget-qprintpreviwwidget/52074632#52074632