# Ho can I draw further elements (like page numbers) while printing a Qt text document?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am writing a numerator program for accountants with PyQt5.

The program should print the specified page ranges (for example, 1-5) on the top right corner of the page, one number per page.

However, when I want to take a printout from the printer, it produces blank pages and I cannot position the page numbers in that corner, and I could not find enough resources on the internet.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter
class PrintDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Yazıcı Yazdırma Ekranı")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        print_button = QPushButton("Yazdır", self)
        print_button.clicked.connect(self.print_document)
        layout.addWidget(print_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def print_document(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        print_dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)

        if print_dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
            painter = QTextEdit(self)
            painter.setPlainText(self.text_edit.toPlainText())

            printer_output = QPrinter.OutputFormat(printer.outputFormat())
            if printer_output == QPrinter.PdfFormat:
                painter.print_(printer)
            else:
                painter.print_(printer_output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = PrintDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It produces blank pages because you provided no contents at all, but that's not the point: you can get the page size from the printer's `pageSize()`. Note that creating a widget "under the hood" like this is not a good idea: you're reparenting it, but you're never destroying it after using it, so you'll have a memory leak. Also, the `printer_output` argument of the second call to `print_()` has a wrong type and it will raise an exception; besides, it's actually unclear what would be the purpose of that choice.

Comment: If your intent is to paint *over* the contents of the current document, that won't work, as the `print()` helper functions (as any drawing on a QPrinter) do not allow to do that: it would be like telling your printer to draw the page numbers **after** it has printed all pages. The **only** way to add custom content to a text document that is going to be printed is by manually do the drawing within the QTextDocument context; it's feasible, but certainly *not* easy. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074632).

Comment: Pycharm Expected type 'QPagedPaintDevice', got 'OutputFormat' instead, gives warning.

Comment: As already said, those are IDE warnings, ***NOT*** program errors, please learn the difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
def print_document(self):
    printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
    print_dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)

    if print_dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(printer)

        # Draw page numbers in the upper right corner of the A4 page
        for i in range(1, 6):
            painter.drawText(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100), Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignTop, str(i))

        painter.end()
```

Comment: Where should i add this piece of code ? Sorry i am new to programming.

Comment: You have to replace the `print_document()` function in your code with the code i have provided. Please see i have edited the code in my answer so that you can replace it straight away

Comment: @AlperenSarı do mark the answer solved you it worked for u ...

Comment: Thank you for your help, but pycharm throws an error "Unresolved attribute reference 'AlignRight' for class 'Qt'".

Comment: @AlperenSarı sorry i used `QPrinter.OutputFormat(printer.outputFormat())` Instead, it should be `printer.outputFormat()` .It should work now

Comment: Sorry but ı couldn't see it again. (I don't understand what to change)

Comment: And the program should get the first page and last page value from the user. As I understand it, we defined certain pages here.

Comment: @AlperenSarı i have tried taking a different approach please see this code if it works

Comment: I tried but got the same warning again.

Comment: @AlperenSarı really sorry... all you have to do is to import Qt.....from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

Comment: it's already imported and same warning.

Comment: @AlperenSarı try using QtCore.Qt.AlignRight in place of Qt.AlignRight. I am also not very experienced so, its getting a bit messy. Sorry, for the inconvenience you are facing

Comment: No problem i will keep working. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: @AlperenSarı did the last change i suggested  solved your problem?

Comment: @AlperenSarı That's a warning from the syntax highlighter, it's not an error in the program. Just run the code.

Comment: @nischalsharma Did you actually try your code? It will just draw numbers superimposed at the same position, which will also **not** be the top right corner of the page, but the top right corner of that *small* rectangle.

Comment: @musicamante No, i dint tried running it

Comment: @nischalsharma Well, then you should, and then you should also consider editing your question in order to provide a *valid* example, possibly with a proper, even if succinct, explanation, as code-only answers are normally frown upon.

Comment: I've tried nothing changes fellas. I couldn't move forward I'm still in the same place